# Problem compatibility symfony/symfony 3.3.* and symfony/dotenv 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

Problem compatibility

This mounted in docker

Problem execute

```
compose exec php ./install.sh
```

my file contains

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

ERROR:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/dotenv v3.4.15 -> satisfiable by symfony/dotenv[v3.4.15].
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.18|don't install symfony/dotenv v3.4.15
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.3.18 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.18].


Warning: require(/var/www/symfony/bin/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/symfony/bin/console on line 15

Call Stack:
    0.0001     367080   1. {main}() /var/www/symfony/bin/console:0


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/symfony/bin/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/symfony/bin/console on line 15

Call Stack:
    0.0001     367080   1. {main}() /var/www/symfony/bin/console:0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My solution: composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Try so: Update symfony and install after symfony/dotenv

Comment: Solution: composer dump-autoload